# jasmine-node pass ressults

Tags: node.js, jasmine-node

i´m trying to check several requirements on a html body, received by the node-module request with jasmine-node.

The normal case would be to write something like this:

```
describe("check website body", function() {
   it("should contain 1st requirement", function(done) {
      request("url...", function(error, response, body) {
          //check here the body for the first requirement
          done();
       });


   }); 

 it("should contain 2nd requirement", function(done) {
      request("url...", function(error, response, body) {
          //check here the body for the 2nd requirement

       });
       done();

   }); 

});
```

What i would like to have is to call the website directly after the describe line and than pass body to the specific tests.

UPDDATE: To clarify: My intention is to only call the url once for my tests, not twice.

could someone can give me a hint how to do this?

Thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You already had the right place in your example, just missing the code!

```
request("url...", function(error, response, body) {
  //check here the body for the first requirement
  expect(body).toContain('something');
  done();
});
```

Comment: Sorry you missunderstood me. I know how to check this. My question is how to pass the body var to both of the it() functions to not call the url twice for the test.